# Not Negah but Like a Negah 

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, tzaraas-negaim, parashat-metzora

Why when calling the Cohen even if you clearly know the Psak you cant say I have a Negah at home Instead of saying  "Kanegah Nireh Li Babayis" Like a Negah?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

*Tos'fos Yom Tov* to *N'gaim* 12:5 gives the following answers, if I read him right:

1. (from the *Mizrachi* in the name of his teachers) Since he can't be sure it's a *nega* until the *kohen* shows up, he shouldn't say he's sure.
2. (from the *Mizrachi* himself) He should treat the *kohen* with *derech eretz*, etc. [The *Tos'fos Yom Tov* includes the "etc.", thereby referring the reader to the *Mizrachi* for a fuller explanation. I didn't check the *Mizrachi* or, indeed, the other people he quotes.]
3. (from the *Mizrachi* himself again) So the *kohen* not be swift to judge it as *tame*. [I assume this means that he'll be prejudicing the *kohen*; however, see the *Chazon Ish*'s answer, below.]
4. (from the *Gur Arye*) It's not a *nega* until the *kohen* says it is, and he shouldn't lie. (The *Korban Aharon* asks that that's not true: the *kohen* says it's *tame*, but it's a *nega tahor* even before pronounced *tame* by the *kohen*. The *Tos'fos Yom Tov* answers that "*nega*" in the vernacular means a *tame* one, so he'd be lying to call it that.)
5. (his own) Because of *al tiftach pe l'satan*.

*Midrashim* quoted by the *Tora Sh'lema* say that this is the source of "*al tiftach pe l'satan*" [which I guess means that they agree with the *Tos'fos Yom Tov*'s own answer].

Rabbi Matis Blum of Queens, in his "Torah Lodaas" weekly *d'var-Tora* sheet for *M'tzora* 5771, suggests that according to those who say there never was or will be a house with *tzaraas*, "*k'nega*" makes sense, as it isn't, in fact, a *nega*.

*Ralbag* says it's because only the *kohen* can adjudge it a *nega*. [This is opaque to me, but perhaps he means the *Mizrachi*'s teachers' or the *Gur Arye*'s answer?]

*Rav Moshe* (in *Darash Moshe*) says it's so as not to say something bad. [This, too, is opaque to me. Perhaps he means the *Tos'fos Yom Tov*'s own answer, or *en m'shivin al hakalkala*?]

Rabbi *Chayim* Zuckerman, in his *sefer Otzar Chayim* on *chumash*, quotes רמה״כ‎ (?) as saying that because *tzaraas* appears on a house because of *tzarus ayin*, the owner's saying it's a *nega* is effectively his libeling himself.

Abarbanel says he should make himself seem uncertain and not like he's smart. [This answer seems to me like the *Mizrachi*'s teachers' answer, but I'm not convinced they're the same.]

In *Esh Kodesh*, the Piazetzner says that the homeowner is unable to see on his own whether the *tzaraas* is a good thing in disguise (so as to get hidden valuables) or simply a bad thing (a *nega*), so all he can say is that looks like a *nega* to him.

Rabbi *Avraham Yitzchak Shayn* of the Yeshiva of Staten Island writes in his book, *Birkas Ish*, that the homeowner, if he were sure that he were not guilty and that the *tzaraas* were so he could get hidden valuables, would be glad to announce he has a *nega*; on the other hand, if he thought he might be guilty and that the *tzaraas* were a punishment, he would only say it's *k'nega*; so the Torah is telling him that he should think he might be guilty and examine his deeds.

The *Malbim*, if I understand him correctly, seems to be saying that the problem is one like *more halacha bifne rabo*.

*Chazon Ish* says that if the homeowner is a *talmid chacham* then the *kohen* will need to rule like the owner said, that there is, in fact, a *nega*, since, although only a *kohen* can rule on a *nega*, anyone can check it. (This works, he notes, according to those who hold a homeowner can check a *nega* on his own home, which he says is a matter of dispute among *rishonim*.) And if the owner is not a *talmid chacham* (or if he saw it at night or under other circumstances that don't count) then (a) saying it's a *nega* is lying and (b) one shouldn't begin talking by saying something bad.